# Animating TextBlock Text in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a statusbar in my application whose content is a `TextBlock`. When my application is running I'd like the textblock text to display `Processing...` but with the number of dots increasing and decreasing. Is this possible?

Note: I dont want to use the progressbar

Comment: is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205502/wpf-not-updating-textbox-while-in-progress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a String animation, like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StringAnimationStoryboard">
  <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Processing" KeyTime="0:0:0.1" />
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Processing." KeyTime="0:0:0.2" />
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Processing.." KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Processing..." KeyTime="0:0:0.4" />
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Processing...." KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
    <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Processing....." KeyTime="0:0:0.6" />
  </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="StringAnimationStyle">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="TextBlock.Loaded" >
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StringAnimationStoryboard}" />
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Be aware though, if you are doing processor-intense calculations in the main application thread, the animation might not run ...