# TextBlock Will Not Update

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, textblock

I have a text block called "findListText". Here, I am updating the text in it:

```
private void InstantSearch(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        HitEnter = true;
    }
    findListText.Text = "Processing request. Please wait...";
    Find(bool.Parse("False" as string));
}
```

However, the next set of code is a search function that can take up to 10 seconds, and at the end of it, it changes the text in findListText again.

```
private void Find(bool? bForward = true)
{
    {
        //Lots and lots of code
    }
    findListText.Text = "Search completed."
}
```

The problem is, the textblock never seems to update to "Processing request. Please wait...". The textblock is in it's original state and 10 seconds later updates to "Search completed.", seemingly skipping out the middle man.

I'm using C# - WPF. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What technology are we talking about? WPF? Win Forms? Web Forms?

Comment: What technology is this? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET?

Comment: BTW, note that you don't need that first `if`. Simply change it to `HitEnter = e.Key == Key.Return;`

Comment: It's a xaml form - not web based. That is, WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't matter what technology I think.

The code is running on the same thread, meaning the the UI won't be updated untill all the code on that thread is completed. You should address a different thread to update that textblock.

In that case, you will have 2 thread:

- The origininal thread, executing the "lots and lots of code"
- The second (extra) created thread, which will handle updating the textblock's text while the other thread is executing the other code.

I've created [a little something](https://www.dropbox.com/s/57yzv0vhnyujnk3/Threading.zip?m) that should resolve your problem, it's based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205502/wpf-not-updating-textbox-while-in-progress) Stack Overflow page

Comment: I expect this is exactly the problem, but I'm not sure how I would go about creating a separate thread just for updating the textblock.

Comment: You don't need all that, all you have to do is to update the UI. Check my answer and give me any feedback, please.

Comment: @AndreCalil: your answer is what is described here, except you don't check if the object is owned by the thread.

Comment: @djerry I don't understand how the link you provided can be used in my specific situation. Could you possibly clarify this for me? Thanks.

Comment: You are right, that solution is for a slightly different problem. I'll update the answer and work more on the solution app.

Comment: @djerry Many thanks! I look forward to hearing your ideas. I've looked at all the other answers and nothing seems to quite match the issue.

Comment: Edited post, hopefully this solves it. Good suggestion from Aphelion, but was missing something.

Comment: @djerry Stupid computer doesn't have .rar opening capabilities. Think you could re-upload it as a zip for me to check out? Thanks.

Comment: @Djerry "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." It seems if I use your method, it cannot get variables from outside this thread I've created.

Comment: @djerry Indeed it is. I'm unfamiliar with the error, but believe many, many lines of the long running code will also throw this error and not just this first one that the program finds.

Comment: @djerry I have a Datatable that often has results written to it, and this is displayed in the UI, apart from that; no. Indeed, it is not even _necessarily_ these lines that cause the exception, however.

Comment: When working in that pool, everything that has impact on the UI needs to be invokes, the same way your textblock is updated.

Comment: @djerry I understand this, but like I previously mentioned, even lines that do not have an impact on the UI seem to be throwing said error. I shall have to have a further look into it.

Comment: @djerry I believe what you have given me is the correct answer, and it's just a case of methodically going through my 1000 line code and editing it all... Fun! Thanks for the offer of additional support, but I think you've answered the initial question.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is WPF, try the following: after changing the text to "Processgin", call:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { this.UpdateLayout(); }));
```

This will tell the thread to update the UI as soon as possible.

Comment: @djerry Indeed. However, as far as we know the application, it's a single thread.

Comment: I have mixed success with this. I essentially have two search functions, one which takes milliseconds, and the long 10 second one. If I use this line of code for the short search the "Processing request" message appears, if only for a split second. On using this line of code with the long 10 second search, nothing happens.

Comment: This fix is hit and miss overall and is not the right way to handle these situations. Think about it - How can the UI update if the UI thread is busy doing work? This type of situation is exactly why `BackgroundWorker` was created.

Comment: @Robbo905 Have you tried chaging the text before the long-time processing?

Comment: @AndreCalil Indeed, the "Processing request" message should appear before any search takes place. Like previously mentioned, this does work on the very short search, but doesn't on the 10 second hanging search.

Comment: @AndreCalil This seems to work about 2% of the time, testing it. So it does actually do something, but not nearly all the time. Why do you think that is?

Comment: @Robbo905 I'm sorry man, I don't know what could be happenning. I'll run some tests here (again)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the UI threading concept of WPF. Invoke the `Dispatcher` to modify the textbox. Also the search should run with `ThreadPool.QueueWorkerItem`.

```
// Start worker thread
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
    // Long running logic here
   findListText.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => findListText.Text = "Processing request. Please wait...");
   Find(bool.Parse("False" as string)); 


    // Tip: Run change on GUI thread from the worker using the dispatcher
    findListText.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => findListText.Text = "Search completed.");
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin with this one. I seem to be getting a "'System.Threading.ThreadPool' does not contain a definition for 'QueueWorkerItem'" error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to run your find method in its own thread.

```
private void InstantSearch(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        HitEnter = true;
    }
    findListText.Text = "Processing request. Please wait...";
    BackgroundWorker tempWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    tempWorker.DoWork += delegate
    {
       Find(bool.Parse("False" as string));
    };
    tempWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

If you try that, you'll get an error because you access your UI thread from the background thread. So you'll need to update your find method as well.

```
private void Find(bool? bForward = true)
{
   {
       //Lots and lots of code
   }
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
      findListText.Text = "Search completed."
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this just now, and had another browse across the internet for similar problems. For something as simple as pushing a single message before a long running process occurs, I'm surprised no-one suggested "Application.DoEvents();". Yes, I know it has it's flaws, and my UI will still hang, but this suits me perfectly for my situation, at least.

Comment: Having said that, it still isn't perfect.