# Print transient text in a textBlock: WP8 and dispatcher magic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone development and I am trying to do something which I believe is quite simple: I have a page, with a button and a textBlock. I would like that, whenever the button is pressed, the textBlock's text change to "Bazinga!" for a few seconds and then revert to its previous value.

I have tried the code below but it does not work (I suppose because the textBlock's display is not refreshed while still in the Button_Click call).

After looking up a few keywords, I saw this: [WPF not updating textbox while in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205502/wpf-not-updating-textbox-while-in-progress)

This tells me I must explicitly call the Dispatcher's Invoke method... but I only see a BeginInvoke() method (I guess this is a specificity of Windows Phone) and my few attempts at getting it right have been unlucky.

Thanks for any help you can

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Function();
}

private void Function()
{
    string text = this.TextBlock1.Text;
    DateTime until = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5.0);
    this.TextBlock1.Text = "Bazinga!";
    while (DateTime.Now < until)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
    this.TextBlock1.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: Are you using an MVVM approach?. Also, DON'T DO `while (DateTime.Now < until) {}`. It's busy waiting, and just keeps running . use a timer, or sleep, or wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = TextBlock1.Text;
    TextBlock1.Text = "Bazinga!";
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    TextBlock1.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! (Well, after referring the System.Threading.Tasks). Thank you so much for your help @pantaloons - and for the introduction to Threading issues in C#.