# Text in a TextBox does not update instantly when change it in the code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf

In the simplified code below, I want the text box to say "Please wait.." while the result is being fetched. However it never appears, instead the textBox only displays the result of `functionThatTakesASecondOrTwoToRun()`

xaml...

```
<Button Name="readDutButton" Content="Read DUT" Click="readDutButton_Click"/>
<TextBox Name="resultTextBox"/>
```

code behind....

```
    private void readDutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultTextBox.Text = "Please wait...";   # this never appears

        result = functionThatTakesASecondOrTwoToRun();

        resultTextBox.Text = result;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF not updating textbox while in progress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205502/wpf-not-updating-textbox-while-in-progress)

Comment: What is the return type of `functionThatTakesASecondOrTwoToRun();`? Also use `x:Name` instead of `Name`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for reference.

Comment: It is not a duplicate as the question refered to is for a particular case which I cant figure out how to convert to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work needs to happen in a background thread, e.g

```
resultTextBox.Text = "Please wait...";   // this never appears

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => functionThatTakesASecondOrTwoToRun())
.ContinueWith((t) => resultTextBox.Text = t.Result, 
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The UI is not getting a change to update as the the UI is blocking the thread.  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() so the ContinueWith is executed on the UI thread and has access to the controls.

Comment: Wait, In one of the places it doesnt work because it reads the value of another text box and I get an exception when I try to access this other text box within `functionThatTakesASecondOrTwoToRun()`  "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Get these values first outside of the task and pass them into the function

Answer (score 2):

In addition to James Simpson's answer, here's another way:

```
resultTextBox.Text = "Please wait...";
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.Background);
result = functionThatTakesASecondOrTwoToRun();
resultTextBox.Text = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

TextBox.Text Property, sets to the most recent value that is assigned. Hence You are not able to see the "please wait...". You may try the following way:
1. Show the Please wait in a text box
2. Hide the please wait text box once you have the value and show the value in another text box

Method 2:
You can use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); in between the lines

Hope this helps.